# bootstrap 3 pull-right button cut off from bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="loginBtn" >Login</button>
```

The addition of `pull-right` makes button cut off from bottom:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding `clearfix` class to its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 button class "btn" adds display: inline-block, which "Displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is formatted as an inline-level box" (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). A way around this would be to try the class "clearfix" around the parent (as was explained above). You could also try wrapping the button in a div:

```
<div class="pull-right"><button></button></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it's inside a Bootstrap `form-group`..

```
<form class="form col-md-12 center-block">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Login</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

### Demo: http://bootply.com/106344